# Force navbar to not overlap content on in-page navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple web page with a `navbar` and some content.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a id="about" href="#first">First section</a></li>
        <li><a id="about" href="#second">Second section</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img alt="this should be my image" />
            <h3 id="first">The first section</h3>
            <p>... content ...</p>
            <h3 id="second">The second section</h3>
            <p>... content ...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `navbar` links to sections in the same page. Whenever a link is clicked, the page scrolls to the targeted element but the content gets overlapped by the `navbar`. Concretely, if the link to the first section is clicked (`First`) the page gets scrolled to the first `h3` element, but the element is actually rendered under the `navbar` element How can this be fixed? See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9uaypLc/) for details -- decrease the height of the results panel to better see the problem.

Comment: Isn't your example missing `navbar-fixed-top` or similar?

Comment: @cvrebert, it's all in the fiddle. It didn't make sense to copy all of it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSS only solution would be to add `padding` to the `h3` `id` and a negative `margin` to remove the redundant whitespace. For example:

```
#first, #second {
    padding-top: 200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

**[See my JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ejc08961/)**